# Simplification of sqrt(c^2) for complex numbers

Tags: simplifying-expressions, mathematical-optimization

if I'm correct one should have

$\sqrt{c^2}=\pm c$.

The plus sign holds if the argument of $c$ is in $[0,\pi)$ and the minus sign holds if the argument of $c$ is in $[\pi,2 \pi)$.

I want mathematica to do this simplification if I give an assumption. But for example

```
Refine[(c^2)^(1/2), Assumptions -> Im[c] > 0]
```

still gives me not the simplification.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the correct statement is that the sign depends on the sign of the real part of `c`. For instance,

```
z = -1 + I;
Sqrt[z^2]
```

> 1 - I

is an example where the sign is -1 even though the imaginary part of z is greater than 0. Using [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine) (or [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify) etc.) yields:

```
Refine[Sqrt[c^2], Assumptions -> Re[c] < 0]
Refine[Sqrt[c^2], Assumptions -> Re[c] > 0]
```

> -c
>
> c

Comment: does not your result depend on the `Assumptions`? I thought that the OP ask for how to get a unique general result ;))

Comment: Ok. I think I just have defined the complex bijective square function differently from mathematica. I have defined in my post z -> z^2 , R^+ \times [0,pi) -> C , but I guess mathematica has the definition  z -> z^2 , R^+ \times [-pi/2,pi/2) -> C. That makes the difference and caused my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for if you use `PowerExpand`:

```
PowerExpand[((a + I b)^2)^(1/2), Assumptions -> True] // Factor
```

$(a+i b) e^{i \pi  \left\lfloor \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\arg (a+b i)}{\pi }\right\rfloor }$

where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the `Floor` function

Comment: Why do you need Assumptions -> True ?

Comment: As it is commented in the reference to include ALL possible results.

Comment: @JanSE `Assumptions -> True` assumes each variable can take on *any* complex value. The default `Assumptions -> Automatic` will make assumptions on the variables that make simple power canceling identities true.